# WSO2 AS features inside WSO2 ESB server

Tags: wso2, application-server, wso2-esb

I install AS 5.2.0 features inside ESB 4.7.0 with some issues:

1. The try it functionallity does´nt work. The UI is broken.
2. When I call a dataservice deployed in a external AS using a proxy service it work OK, but if the dataservice is deployed in the same ESB I recieve a binary payload when I called it using a proxy service. I try this using SOAPUI, the dataservice response is OK but the proxy service not.
3. The SOAPtracer only show the dataservice request/response and not the proxy servic request/response.

How can I fix this issues?

EDIT:

...I was using AS 5.1.0 first but I found that if I activate the SOAPtracer I recieve this response message from proxy service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis2ns7:binary xmlns:axis2ns7="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">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</axis2ns7:binary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if I dissable soaptracer I can recieve the right response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <datosCollection xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <datos>
            <id>1</id>
            <nombre>nombre1</nombre>
         </datos>
         <datos>
            <id>2</id>
            <nombre>nombre2</nombre>
         </datos>
         <datos>
            <id>3</id>
            <nombre>nombre3</nombre>
         </datos>
         <datos>
            <id>5</id>
            <nombre>nombre5</nombre>
         </datos>
         <datos>
            <id>4</id>
            <nombre>nombre4</nombre>
         </datos>
         <datos>
            <id>10</id>
            <nombre>gero et</nombre>
         </datos>
      </datosCollection>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With AS 5.1.0 features taken from 4.1.0 P2 repo the Try it functionallity is broken for dataservices and for proxy services.

Another question related with BPS, if i want to install BPS features in ESB 4.7.1 with P2 repo I need to use?

Comment: Can you try to un install all javascript related features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS 5.2.0 is based on Carbon 4.2.0 while ESB 4.7.0 is based on Carbon 4.1.0.
When you are mixing features of different products they should have the same Carbon core version.

So you should try using AS 5.1.0 with ESB 4.7.0.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately it seems like there are some compatibility issues in features of 4.1 patch releases which introduces these problem for AS 5.1.0 with ESB 4.7.0. You better try with Carbon 4.2 based products. AS 5.2.0 and ESB 4.8.0 (to be released this week). Also Carbon 4.2 based BPS new version will be released in December.

Comment: I have ESB 4.8.0(v4.2.0) and BPS 3.1.0(v4.2.0) products but I cannot find the BPS features in the Turing P2 repo. Do you have any idea when this features will be releases in a P2 repo?

Answer (score 5):

Yes all the issues you raised are correct.

Try it functionality is broken after installing the features. So we encourage you to use soap-ui.

Putting soap tracer 'on' is the root cause for getting binary responses. So you better put soap tracer 'off' and use tcp mon which is embedded with any wso2 product to trace requests and responses. Then it works fine.

Since last BPS was released under carbon 4.0.0, you cannot install its features into ESB 4.7 which was released under carbon 4.1.0. But ESB 4.8 and BPS 3.1.0 will be released under carbon 4.2.0 soon and you can use them with AS 5.2 which has been already released.

You can find wso2 product release matrix from [here](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/)

Comment: Hi Vimesh. I have ESB 4.8.0 and BPS 3.1.0 products but I cannot find the BPS features in the Turing P2 repo. Do you have any idea when this features will be releases in a P2 repo?