# WSO2 Carbon Feature Stack - UES and Data Services Server

Tags: wso2

I would like to create a carbon server composed of multiple features; namely the User Engagement Server (UES) and the Data Services Server (DSS). UES is only carbon 4.1.0 based and DSS is 4.2.0 or 3.0.1 based. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what are my alternatives for utilizing the functionality of both features set?

I have looked over wso2.org and other resources for help; however, I'm failing to find best practices for deploying a custom carbon solution and upgrading to future version. In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231284/wso2-as-features-inside-wso2-esb-server) I found a [compatibility matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/), but the answer indicates that there is neither forward or backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 products will have API level changes between two different platform releases (as in 4.1.0 vs 4.2.0 [Turing]). So installing features from different platform versions will not work in most cases.

However, UES does have features based on a carbon 4.2.0 kernel (UES 1.0.1) and you can install the required features from the latest p2 feature repository [here](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/). It includes UES 1.0.1 feature which is based on Carbon 4.2.0 kernel. You might want to wait till DSS 3.1.1 is officially released (due to be released in about a week) which has some important bug fixes and improved stability.

To get features of both products, it would be easier to install UES features on top of a DSS product or vice versa, rather than installing both feature sets on a bare bones carbon server, since you may have to additionally install some kernel patches, configuration files, which are not installed during a feature installation.

HTH,